# Discord bot permissions not working as intended

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to write a simple discord bot that queries through a movie database and returns the results based on the search query made by the user. Issue is I can't seem to figure out the required discord permissions for this to work. The only way I managed to make it work was to give it administrative permission which is something I don't want. Below are the permissions that I gave for my bot. And the code that I am using.

[image]

#### My code base:

```py
import discord
import os
from run_server import serve
from dotenv import load_dotenv

from versions.v2.utils import get_query_list, get_movie_detail_query

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

load_dotenv()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as user {0.user}".format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("!search"):
        content = message.content
        param = content.split(" ", 1)[1]
        print("search log: ", param)
        try:
            await message.channel.send(get_query_list(param))
        except Exception as e:
            await message.channel.send(
                f"Oops! Can't find any search results for {param}"
            )

    if message.content.startswith("!details"):
        content = message.content
        param = content.split(" ", 1)[1]
        print("details log: ", param)

        try:
            await message.channel.send(get_movie_detail_query(param))
        except Exception as e:
            await message.channel.send("No thoughts in my head at the moment")
            print(str(e))


serve()
client.run(os.environ["TOKEN"])
```

#### The error I get:

```bash
[2023-09-29 14:55:03] [ERROR   ] discord.client: Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kazem/projects/filmy/filmy/main.py", line 30, in on_message
    await message.channel.send(get_query_list(param))
  File "/home/kazem/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 1562, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, params=params)
  File "/home/kazem/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 739, in request
    raise Forbidden(response, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kazem/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kazem/projects/filmy/filmy/main.py", line 32, in on_message
    await message.channel.send(
  File "/home/kazem/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 1562, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, params=params)
  File "/home/kazem/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 739, in request
    raise Forbidden(response, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
search log:  how to use filmy
[2023-09-29 15:02:42] [ERROR   ] discord.client: Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kazem/projects/filmy/filmy/main.py", line 30, in on_message
    await message.channel.send(get_query_list(param))
  File "/home/kazem/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 1562, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, params=params)
  File "/home/kazem/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 739, in request
    raise Forbidden(response, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kazem/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kazem/projects/filmy/filmy/main.py", line 32, in on_message
    await message.channel.send(
  File "/home/kazem/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 1562, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, params=params)
  File "/home/kazem/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 739, in request
    raise Forbidden(response, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

#### How it's supposed to work:

[image]

I tried to check one by one activating the permissions to narrow down which permissions I needed. But had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error it seems that your bot doesn't have the `Send Messages` permission in the channel you're using the command in.

Comment: How though? Is there any other `Send Messages`  permission that I am not aware of ? Because I clearly added that permission as I have indicated in the first image.